# Does there exist a switch with wire already attached to it?

Tags: switches, wire

Maybe it's a silly question, but I lose a great amount of time to solder wire to an on-on 6 row (DPSP) switch. I would like to know if there is a switch sold somewhere (cheap) with wire already soldered (12 inches is long enough) to it, or if there is a plug (female) that can be used to connect switch. It's very small:

[image: DPDT Toggle]

- http://www.parts-express.com/pe/showdetl.cfm?partnumber=060-538

Comment: Why not use a quick-connect terminal?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Quick-connect terminal is the plug he's looking for.  That is, if the switch has terminals compatible with quick-connect.  Since the O.P. haven't posted a reference to the switch, we have no way of knowing.

Comment: picture reference posted.. sorry

Comment: You should learn to solder wires to those mini toggle switches - if you do much electronics,  you _will_ be soldering to much smaller things.  To work with those switches, you need small wire (I prefer AWG 24), thin solder and a fine-tip soldering iron.

Comment: I know how to solider, but some times, i need 2 or 3 wire on one pin, and then, it became a pain in the a$$

Comment: So then only solder 1 wire, and use a wire nut or similar solution for the rest.

Comment: Note that if you need 3 wires to one pin the switch you are asking for with pre-soldered wires will not help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Solder Lugs

The terminals on the switch you linked are known as "eye" terminals or solder "lugs." They're designed to be easy to solder to.

If you're feeling like soldering to these switches is difficult, there might be a few things you're doing "wrong" or "the hard way."

As with many things, the right tools make the job much easier. I solder these kind of switches all the time, and they go quickly and easily.

You need:

- Good wire strippers
- Good soldering iron/station
- Fine tip needle-nose pliers
- Flush cutter
- Vise or helping hands

### Wire Strippers:

If you're using wire strippers that look like these:

[image: Crappy Wire Strippers]
[image: Teeth]

Stop right there. If you have the things on the left, please go deposit them in your trash right now. Go ahead, I'll wait.

If you're using your teeth, your dentist asked us to please forward the message: ***stop!***

You need to obtain *good* wire strippers. They will make your life a lot easier, trust me. Something like this:

[image: Good Wire Strippers]

Of course there are many kinds, but this one is from Klein (who make very good electrical tools) and they have notches for wire gauges 22 through 32.

The main advantage is that they are accurate and won't leave insulation shreds behind nor nick the conductor. They're not terribly expensive and they will last you a very long time.

### Soldering Iron/Station

Having a good soldering iron or station is the single best investment you can make if you are doing more than just design or theory. There's no need to rehash the subject here, as there are lots of questions on the site that [deal with this topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/1147/2028).

Trust me: if you have an iron that can't maintain temperature, has too small or too large a tip, or has an old corroded tip, that's your main problem.

### Needle Nose Pliers

These aren't absolutely required, but working with wire and components you almost always need a way to bend or shape wire and grasp things between pins and terminals that your fingers are simply too large to fit between.

[image: Needle Nose Pliers]

I have some like these, and they are one of my favorite tools, I kid you not. There's just no substitute for precise bending and gripping that these provide.

### Flush Cutters

When you've soldered the wire, flush cutters afford you the ability to nip the excess wire with ease. You therefore don't have to strip the wire to a specific length, you can strip excess that is convenient, insert the wire in the lug, and snip the excess when done. These are also generally cheap, so not having them is no excuse:

[image: Flush Cutters]

### Vise / Helping Hands

For soldering a panel-mount component like a switch, before it's actually in a panel, you need something to hold it steady while you solder. Nothing is more aggravating than trying to solder onto a component that's just sitting on the bench and you're trying to be careful and not tip it over.

[image: Helping Hands]
[image: Panavise]

At left is the popular "Helping Hands" tool, and at right a Panavise Jr. (I even put a DPDT switch in it for you.)

Position the switch in the holder, strip your wire, insert partly through the eye, solder, trim excess (if needed), and move on.

[image: Wiring Solder Lug]

---

Finally, if you really don't want to solder to the lugs on your switches, you should consider female spade connectors. You can buy these already attached to lengths of wire and then you only need to solder the wires to your PCB or whatever the switch controls. However if you just get the spade connectors and have to crimp them on yourself, you're not saving any time.

[image: Female Space Connectors]

Comment: I still use my teeth but +1 for the good advice

Comment: I used to use my teeth too. I only do that now if I am truly without a decent tool nearby; i.e. desperate. :)